# Select from SQLite database if entry is from 'today'.Timestamp is GMT but SELECT should be timezone specific

Tags: sqlite

I have a list of tasks stored in an SQLite database with timestamp in GMT format as follows:

```
Timestamp: 2014-07-10 00:42:43
```

I am trying to get all 'todays tasks' but 'today' relevant to the timezone. (so the above Timestamp example in Eastern Standard time is actually a task from the July 9th not the 10th

My query:

```
"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS + " WHERE date('timestamp','localtime') >= date('now', 'start of day','localtime')"
```

Doesn't select the tasks when the GMT time has rolled over to the next day even though in EST it is still july 9th.

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
> create table t(timestamp);
> insert into t values (datetime('now'));
> select date('timestamp') from t;

> select date("timestamp") from t;
2014-07-10
> select date(timestamp) from t;
2014-07-10
```

In SQL, anything enclosed in single quotes is a string, and `timestamp` is not a date/time value in one of the [supported formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

If you wanted to [quote an identifer](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) (i.e., a table or column name), you would need to use double quotes.
However, `timestamp` is not a keyword, so you don't need to quote it at all.